# New to javascript, how would I embed my javascript file and run it in an HTML field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a rock, paper, scissors simulator in javascript (in a file) which takes a user input, generates an AI choice, and compares them, and then returns the answer. How would I go about doing all of this within an HTML field, so the user can see everything that's going on? Code is below:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
console.log("You chose: " + userChoice);
var compare = function (choice1) { 
    var choice2 = Math.random();
    if (choice2 < 0.34) {
       choice2 = "rock";
       console.log("The computer chose: " + choice2);
    } else if(choice2 <= 0.67) {
        choice2 = "paper";
        console.log("The computer chose: " + choice2);
    } else {
        choice2 = "scissors";
        console.log("The computer chose: " + choice2);
    }

    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        } else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    }
    if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "rock wins";
        } else {
            return "scissors win";
        }
    }
    if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        } else {
            return "scissors win";
        }
    }
};
compare(userChoice);
```

Comment: Do you know how to set a value to a form input?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:
replace console.log with this:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerText = "text that you want"
```

and add to the html

```
<h2 id="result"></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you typed `jquery` as a tag, you should use jQuery's `.html()` function to insert your output into a `<div>` or other element, instead of outputting to console.

Ex:

create

```
<div id="output">

</div>
```

Then instead of `console.log("You chose: " + userChoice);`, write:

```
$("#output").html("You chose: " + userChoice);
```

Comment: How would I then call my file in a text area say?

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify what you mean? If you mean how you would have your javascript in an HTML file, you simply either reference it in your HTML file (see here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html) or you put in within script tags: `<script>... your code here... </script>`

Comment: Say something like;
<textarea id = "output">
                    <script src = "work/rockpaperscissors.js"></script>
                </textarea>
This doesn't work so  how would I go about run the file through the text area? Or would be easier to just write the code?

Comment: The javascript reference doesn't go in `<textarea>` or any other HTML element within the `<body>`. You have to place it in the `<head></head>` section. Read up on referencing javascript files by Googling. Then, if you want to output text into the `<textarea>` field, use what I specified at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: This is how it all works: You have an HTML file, then you have some javascript code. You can either place that javascript code directly in your HTML file by putting `<script></script>` tags in the `<head>`, at the top of the `<body>`, or usually people place it at the very bottom of the `<body>`, OR you can place your javascript code in another file and reference it in your HTML file, as described in the link I gave you above. THEN within/using your javascript code itself you specify where you want to output your dynamically generated text.